# Convert sql to Lambda expression

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, lambda

Guy's I need a Lambda expression for this sql statement.

```
select GalleryId, Max(Bid)
from BidModels
where GalleryId in (select GalleryId from BidModels where UserId = (UserId))
group by GalleryId
```

Comment: userid = userid is a no-op (always true).  Did you intend one of those to be an input parameter?

Comment: Sorry yes userid is variable should be UserId = some parr?

Comment: You sure you mean lambda or is it LINQToSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need the subquery, given that you can just select all Bids where UserId = userid being passed in. With that in mind:

```
var userid = <whatever>;

var query = from b in BidModels
            where b.UserId = userid
            group by b.GalleryId into g
            select new {Id = g.Key, MaxBid = g.Max(x => x.Bid)};
```

Comment: I am attempting to query the database for produce bids specific to a user relevant to bids from all users. In other words I want a single bidder to know where his bid stands relevant to other bids for his the same set of produces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

```
var galleryIds = (bidModelses.Where(b => b.UserId == [YOURPARAMETER])
                 .Select(b => b.GalleryId));

var query = (bidModelses.Where(bm => galleryIds.Contains(bm.GalleryId))
            .GroupBy(bm => bm.GalleryId)
            .Select(gbm => new {gbm.Key, MaxBid = gbm.Max(p => p.BidId)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the answer thanks for the help:

```
from b in BidModels
let  MyGallery = from a in BidModels where a.UserId == (1) select new { a.GalleryId }
where MyGallery.Any()
group b.Bid by b.GalleryId into g
select new 
 { Id     = g.Key, 
   MaxBid = g.Max()
 }
```